# Firebase Phone Auth - invalid-phone-number

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate using Firebase phone auth. Following is a dummy code snippet.

```
void firebaseAuthRedirect() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: '+91 ${phoneController.text}',
      verificationCompleted: (authCredential) async {
        // some validations
      },
      verificationFailed: (error) {
        var errorLog =
            "Firebase Phone Auth Failed. \n ErrorCode:- ${error.code}, \n Message:- ${error.message} \n Phone Number:- ${error.phoneNumber} \n StackTrace:- ${error.stackTrace.toString()}.";
        CustomLogger.instance.singleLine(errorLog);
      },
      codeSent: (verificationId, token) {
        // some logic
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {
        some logic 
      },
      forceResendingToken: _resendToken,
    );
  }
```

The login works the first time. What I mean by `first time` is if I try to log in with a number that is not yet registered in Firebase under my account, it works smoothly. If I then clear data or log out, and then try to log in again, the verification fails to cite an error `invalid-phone-number`.

When trying to log the phone number, using `error.phoneNumber` in `verificationFailed` callback, it logs `null`. The most unusual part is that the I receive the OTP on the phone number, but at the same time receive the invalid-phone-number error.

What am I missing here?